# How to make accordion's content to be opened even by clicking outside the link's text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

I created an accordion :

```
<div class="box-group" id="accordion">

    <c:forEach items="${groupe_menus}" var="groupe_menu">

        <div class="panel box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h4 class="box-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#content_${groupe_menu.gmnu_code}" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                        ${groupe_menu.gmnu_lib}
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="content_${groupe_menu.gmnu_code}" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                ... // accordion's content
            </div>

        </div>

    </c:forEach>

</div>
```

At runtime it is mandatory to click the accordion's link text to get its content to be opened. So how to make it possible to open the content even by clicking just the box header region ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $("#accordion").find($("div.box-header")).each(function(){
            var region_titre = $(this);
            region_titre.on("click", function(){
                var links = region_titre.find("a");
                var premierlink = links[0];
                premierlink.click();
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```